# How to return two functions in one function in Javascript - NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got in a problem that I have to combine thow objects and return in one function. The problem is that for both objects I have almost the same properties, but the values are different.

So I created two separated functions that have each one same object, almost same props, diff values. 
Inside each function I have a url that gets called for both cases different: case1 = skoda, case2 = toyota.

The problem is that I don't know how to make thow diff get calls(I put a comment there) to have both cars returned in one function, to be listed in one xml link. Now each car is on a separate xml link, because there are in two separated files. Now has to be one link and I can't figure out how to do this.

Please someone can give me a little help?

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const apiUrl = config.api[env];

  const skodaParams = {
    categoryId: 'skoda',
    limit: 1000,
    offset: 0
  };

  const toyotaParams = {
    categoryId: 'toyota',
    limit: 1000,
    offset: 0
  };

const generateSkoda = skoda => {
  // a lot of code for skoda prop
  const skodaList = {
    'g:id': product.carId
    'g:brand': product.brand,
    'g:color': product.color
    'g:teamSkoda: 'Skoda'
  }

  return skodaList;
}

const generateToyota = toyota => {
  // a lot of code for toyota prop
  const skodaList = {
    'g:id': product.carId
    'g:brand': product.brand,
    'g:color': product.color,
    'g:teamToyota: 'Toyota'
  }

  return skodaList;
}

const getSkoda = () => {
  return axios.get(apiUrl, { params: skodaParams });
}
const getToyota = () => {
  return axios.get(apiUrl, { params: toyotaParams });
}


const createBothCars = () => { 

  // here I wanted to add some how two axios get calls for both skoda and toyota
  return axios
    .all([getSkoda(), getToyota()])
    .then(response => {
      console.log('response', response);

      const skodaArray = [];

      response.data.skoda.map(item => {
        return skodaArray.push(generateSkoda(item));
      })

      const Obj = {
        feed: {
          $: {
            xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
            'xmlns:g': 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'
          },
          title: 'Skoda cars list',
          link: {
            $: {
              rel: 'self',
              href: config.domain
            }
          },
          entry: skodaArray
        }
      };

      const objBuilder = new xml2js.Builder({
        cdata: true
      });

      return objBuilder.buildObject(Obj);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

module.exports = createXml;
```

And in server.js I have:

```
const createXml = require('../src/xml/createXml');

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

server.get('/both-cars.xml', (req, res) => {
      res.header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
      (async function sendXML() {
        const xmlFile = await createXml();
        res.send(xmlFile);
      })();
    });
```

**Update**

I updated the code with axios.all, following the comment, but in the response I don't get values from both functions, but I get the values from the last function listed in this array:

[getSkoda(), getToyota()]

now I get the values only from getToyota,

```
data: {
      filters: [Array],
      skoda: [],
      toyota: [Array],
      _version: 'Fri Jun 19 14:43:47 EEST 2020',
      errorCode: 'no_error'
    }
```

if I switch the order [getToyota(), getSkoda()] I will get only the values from getSkoda.

This is from console.log:

```
data: {
      filters: [Array],
      skoda: [Array],
      toyota: null,
      _version: 'Fri Jun 19 14:47:09 EEST 2020',
      errorCode: 'no_error'
    }
```

Any other help?

Comment: You can use axios.all(), for Multiple concurrent requests, please check documentation at https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index  and https://github.com/axios/axios  this will help you further

Comment: @Manoj I uptdated the code. If you can look now in description I showed what I get. There a problem that I don't get the values from both functions.

Comment: Check code in answer, I may help further..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response you should receive two values:

```
return axios
.all([getSkoda(), getToyota()])
.then((responseOne, responseTwo) => {
  console.log('responseOne', responseOne);
  console.log('responseOne', responseOne);
```

Here is the example code that may help further:

```
axios.all([getToyota(), getSkoda()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (toyotaResponse, skodaResponse) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  console.log('toyota Response', toyotaResponse);
  console.log('skoda Response', skodaResponse);
  }))
```

;